# Should I use MySQL Connector/ODBC or the System.Data.Odbc?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, odbc

My application should get data from a MySQL database via an ODBC connection.
Now I am wondering, what connector I should use. Should I download the MySQL Connector/ODBC and add a reference to the dll? Or should I simply use the built-in .NET connector located under System.Data.Odbc?

Do they work both? Are there differences between them both?

EDIT: I don't want to install a specific driver. Unfortunately I didn't see which is the right solution for me, yet.

Comment: In most cases the generic ODBC is not the most performant way to retrieve data and a lot of specific functions for the desired backend are missing. So I would prefer using the native MySQL-connector if possible.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-net.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed that between Connector/ODBC and Connector/NET. There's huge different. Regarding your question, it is about the similar stuff which require ODBC. You still need to install the connector/ODBC to use that built-in System.Data.Odbc

However, I offer you another solution which is using Connector/Net. This connector uses ADO.NET which is more reliable (ref:[MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-net.html)). You should opt for this one if you're using .NET language.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, your .Net application will use a .Net Provider for ?????

System.Data.Odbc is simple a .Net Provider for ODBC Data sources - or a .Net to ODBC Bridge...

So, to use System.Data.Odbc you would also need a suitable ODBC Driver for MySQL.

As LukeH already pointed out MySQL has its own .Net Provider which does not use ODBC at all...

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-net.html

Sometimes it's a case of suck it and see...

Some solutions work where others do not and so on...

Others to consider -

[OpenLink MySQL Multi-Tier .Net Provider](http://uda.openlinksw.com/dotnet-mysql-mt/)

[openLink MySQL Single-Tier ODBC Driver](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-mysql-st/)

Comment: What I don't want to do is to install a driver, before I use my application. I think the Connector/Net supports referencing some DLL file in Visual Studio, which lets me grab data from my database. Why du I have to install a driver, if I want to use Connector/ODBC?